# valid() method of jquery validator is always returning true

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using jquery validator, the input field left as blank and showing its value as empty, but jquery valid() method is always returning true. Actually there are several tabs inside the form, and each click of next the next tab will be shown and previous will be hidden. So we cant validate all the form at once My validation rule is given as:

```
$('#wizard_example_1').validate({
    rules: {
        link_client_name: {
            required: true
        },
        link_page_url: {
            required: true,
            url: true
        },
        link_title: {
            required: true
        },
        link_message: {
            required: true
        },
        link_text: {
            required: true
        },
        link_url: {
            required: true,
            url: true
        }
    }
});
```

and the jquery code to check the elements specificaly if they are valid or not is as

```
$('.next-btn').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     count++;
     if (obj['camp_type'] === "1") {
         var valid = false;
         $.each($('#link input'), function (i, v) {
             var id=$(this).attr('name');
             valid=$('input[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').valid();
         });
         if(valid) {
             obj = {};
             obj['camp_type'] = "1";
             obj['client_name'] = $('#link_client_name').val();
             obj['page_url'] = $('#link_page_url').val();
             obj['title'] = $('#link_title').val();
             obj['message'] = $('#link_message').val();
             obj['action_text'] = $('#link_text').val();
             obj['action_url'] = $('#link_action_url').val();
             console.log(obj);
         }else{
             return false;
         }
     }
});
```

Comment: `valid` would always be the result of the last iteration of `$.each`

Comment: ok, i admit that, but if the last element is empty then it should return false, but it is returning true

Comment: For cases like this, I like to use programmatic validation. I have created [egkyron](https://github.com/nikospara/egkyron), there are also other libraries that do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to Implement with this method.

```js
var $ValidateForm = $('#wizard_example_1').validate({
    rules: {
        link_client_name: {
            required: true
        },
        link_page_url: {
            required: true,
            url: true
        },
        link_title: {
            required: true
        },
        link_message: {
            required: true
        },
        link_text: {
            required: true
        },
        link_url: {
            required: true,
            url: true
        }
    }
});

 $('.next-btn').off();
  $(document).on('click', '.next-btn', function () {
                    if ($ValidateForm.form()) {
                      // your logic 
}
                });
```

Comment: Actually there are several tabs inside the form, and each click of next the next tab will be shown and previous will be hidden. So we cant validate all the form at once